# Can I open / stream a remote file (PDF) in JavaScript and push it to another server?

Tags: javascript, file

I'm building out some internal tools for my staff to streamline processes. One particular task that gets tedious is needing to download a PDF file from one website, and then upload that same file to another website we use to send faxes (Hellofax). Hellofax support email -> fax, so I'd like to build a bookmarklet / browser extension to grab the PDF file instead of forcing the browser to download it, and then send it over to a basic web service that could email the file as an attachment. Is this possible?

Comment: browser-based javascsript cannot open connections to arbitrary sites, or download anything. you can do ajax requests BACK to the same server the containing page came from.

Comment: In the browser, no. This would, however, be possible in Node.

Comment: @MarcB First of all it can: via CORS or websockets or WebRTC (or God knows how many other things there are in JS nowadays). Secondly the OP is asking about browser extensions. Obviously it can be done with them.

Comment: cors needs cooperation from the target site, and cannot just be arbitrary done via client-side code.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, so does HTTP protocol and underlying TCP. So what? He obviously says "from one website". As long as the website supports it, its fine. Your original comment is at least misleading.

Comment: I don't have control over the source site that hosts the PDF file, but I do have complete control over the client environment (browser). Could this be done with a Chrome extension?